# can i change the first tabbar item that appears without changing it's places on the tabbarcontroller

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i have a viewcontroller with a button that when touched take us to a tabbarcontroller by modal (i'm using storyboard), this tabbar controller have 5 items, each taking to a different viewcontroller, but when i click that button it takes me to the first viewcontroller(from item1), can i change it without changing the items order on the tabbar? I want it to go to item 2...

I think i wasn't clear enough, i really don't know how to explain it, but hope you can understand!

i'm not using any code to do that, only storyboard!

Comment: You are trying to get a tab that represents view controller A, to instead take you to view controller B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do this with a storyboard, but normally you would just do this before you bring up your tab bar controller:

`[myTabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];`

or

`[myTabBarController setSelectedViewController:mySecondViewController];`